# Secure Dynamic Updates in Active Directory-integrated DNS server not working

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, internal-dns

Domain Controller +﻿ DNS server is Window Server 2008 R2 Std.

DHCP Server is Cisco Catalyst 3560 & 3750

How to trust this DHCP Server in my Active Directory-integrated DNS Server, so that I can receive secure Dynamic updates on my DNS server.

As of now i have done below setting (Please see below print-screen), i need to change it to ' Dynamic updates: Secure Only '

[image]

Note:- If i keep ' Dynamic updates: Secure only ' than my DNS server don't take any update from my DHCP server.

So, is it possible to trust this DHCP server on my Active Directory-integrated DNS Server?

Regards,

Param

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic updates: Secure Only, support only member server joined to the Domain, didn't support non-Domain device or server (like workgroup)